# Application of Minkowski inequality for integrals

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question regarding Minkowski inequality for integrals:

Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function in $L^p$ with respect to Lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty),\ p\in(1,\infty)$.

Define $F(y)=\int_{(0,1)}f(xy)d\lambda(x),\ y>0$.

Show that $F\in L^p$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty)$ and $||F||_p={p\over{p-1}}||f||_p$.

I am advised to use Minkowski inequality for integrals:

$||F||_p=[\int_{(0,\infty)}|\int_{(0,1)}f(xy)d\lambda(x)|^{p}d\lambda(y)]^{1\over p}\leq\int_{(0,1)}[\int_{(0,\infty)}|f(xy)|^{p}d\lambda(y)]^{1\over p}d\lambda(x)$.

However, I am stucked after reaching this step. Kindly advise to proceed on the working.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it the correct form. Apologies for the typo in the inequality, which I originally didn't notice it as well. :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the correct inequality is (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality)) $$\|F\|_p=\left(\int_{(0,\infty)}\left|\int_{(0,1)}f(xy)d\lambda(x)\right|^{p}d\lambda(y)\right)^{1/ p}\leq\int_{(0,1)}\left(\int_{(0,\infty)}|f(xy)|^{p}d\lambda(y)\right)^{1/ p}d\lambda(x)$$

Now let $xy=z$ and note that

$$\int_{(0,1)}\left(\int_{(0,\infty)}|f(xy)|^{p}d\lambda(y)\right)^{1/ p}d\lambda(x)=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{|f(z)|^p}{x}d\lambda(z)\right)^{1/p}d\lambda (x)$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Oh there is a switch of the sets in integration. Didn't notice that.:P